# FluentProducerTemplate - Request going to wrong rest endpoint

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, grpc

I am calling rest endpoints from a middleware using apache camel. When we run the Performance test the requests are going to different endpoints and their bean validations failed.

It is happening at random and when the load is more. below is the code snippet:

```
   @Component
   public class AccountGrpcService extends RouteBuilder {

     @Autowired
     private FluentProducerTemplate producer; 
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception { 

     getContext().getExecutorServiceManager().setDefaultThreadPoolProfile(
     threadPool.getAccountThreads());
    from(properties.getAccountGrpc())
.doTry()
      .process(processor)
      //.to(properties.getAccountUrl())
      .process(e -> {
        log.info("Before invoking CreateAccount {} request {}", properties.getAccountUrl(), e.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        log.info("getAccountUrl {}",properties.getAccountUrl());
        final String response = producer.withHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE)
                                                    .withBody(e.getIn().getBody(String.class))
                                                      .withHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,"POST")
                                        .to(properties.getAccountUrl()).request(String.class);
        e.getIn().setBody(response);
      })
.doCatch(Exception.class)
      .process(errorHandler);

}
```

**properties.getAccountGrpc()** is GRPC url, it is **from** url.
**properties.getAccountUrl()** is the rest endpoint I am calling.

```
@Component
public class InquiryGrpcService extends RouteBuilder {

   @Autowired
   private FluentProducerTemplate producer; 

   /* @see org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder#configure() */
   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception { 
    getContext().getExecutorServiceManager().setDefaultThreadPoolProfile(
    threadPool.getInquiryThreads());

    from(properties.getActivationGrpc())
    .doTry()
     .process(processor)
     .process(e -> {  
       log.info("Before invoking ServiceActivation {} request {}", 
       properties.getActivationUrl(), e.getIn().getBody(String.class));
       log.info("getActivationUrl {}",properties.getActivationUrl());
       final String response = producer.withHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, 
           "application/json")
                                                   
       .withBody(e.getIn().getBody(String.class))
                                                     
        .withHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,"POST")
                                    
         .to(properties.getActivationUrl()).request(String.class);
       e.getIn().setBody(response);
          })
   .doCatch(Exception.class)
     .process(errorHandler)
    .doFinally()
     .process(exch -> {
       final String responseStr = exch.getIn().getBody(String.class);
       log.info(responseStr);
       exch.getIn().setBody(JsonProtoConvertUtil
                         
    .fromJson(responseStr,ServiceActivationResponse.class));
     }).process(postHandler)
    .convertBodyTo(ServiceActivationResponse.class);
  }
```

Similarly, we have multiple endpoint configurations.  for each [grpc](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/)  request, we are calling a rest endpoint.

How it is going to a different endpoint?

What is the reason for requests are going to another endpoint?